# NPOI in Unity: missing enumeration value in docPropsVTypes, but it works in a regular C# program

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unity-game-engine, npoi

I've built the most recent NPOI code (https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) using VS2015 (with the .NET 2.0 option), and I can run a C# program built in VS2015 to create and manipulate an Excel workbook.  I want to have a Unity C# script use the NPOI library, but when I try to create a workbook with the following line

```
IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

I get an InvalidOperationException, the details of which are at the end of this post.  I'm not familiar with the NPOI code, so I'm really not sure what might be going on here.  What is causing this error?

Here's the error, I've bolded the parts with exceptions, but left in the stack info just in case it's important.  Sorry if it's overkill.

> **InvalidOperationException: Type NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.ItemChoiceType is missing enumeration value 'vstream' for element 'vstream from
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'.**
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>
> **Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'Item'.**
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>
> **Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_Property'.**
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>
> **Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'property'.**
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>
> **Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_CustomProperties'.**
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides,
>   System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute
>   root, System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type)
>   NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument..cctor ()
>
> **Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument**
>
> NPOI.POIXMLProperties..cctor ()
>
> **Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for NPOI.POIXMLProperties**
>
> NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties ()
>
> **Rethrow as POIXMLException**
>
> NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties ()
>   NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook.OnWorkbookCreate ()
>   NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor () TestExcel.Start () (at
>   Assets/TestExcel.cs:10)

Comment: I'm purely curious - why would you want to read Office files in unity ??  sounds cool...

Comment: To animate objects using TSPI files, which are often in Excel format.  It's a long story.